# In Dynamic CRM fill in the field automatically

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to convert or qualify a lead into opportunity, but the lead has some self-define fields and I also want these self-define fields to go into the opportunity automatically. How to do it?

Answer (score 6):

You can do by editing the mapping of the relationship.

[image]

[image]

You can define the source field and the corresponding target field

Comment: What if the "Mappings" section is not there? For example in the "Case to Appointment" relationship that comes out-of-box.

Comment: if you don't see the Mappings section means that is a standard relationship that can't be modified

Answer (score 0):

As Guido said, you just need to modify the Lead- Opportunity Relationship. When you go to your solution, go to the Lead entity and to the relationships tab, there look for the Opportunity one, when you open it you will see a Mappings tab, there you can define which fields will be populated.

However please have in mind that this will only populate the fields on Create of an Opportunity!

If you want to also update automatically that opportunity when you update the lead you will need a plugin to do that.

Cheers,

Mario

Comment: When a lead is qualified to an opportunity `Status Reason` change to `Qualified` and the lead becomes read only. If the lead is reactivated and qualified again a new opportunity record is created. However your advice is useful when the mapping relates to a normal relationship