# Relationship and Mapping in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am really new to MS Dynamics CRM .. and am stuck with understanding the Relationship and Mapping section.

I want to map the "city" field from Account entity to a "city" field in my custom entity "Custom".

For that I navigate to Account entity settings and create a 1:N relationship with related entity as "Custom" and then map the two fields.

Just like how all related data from "Lead" entity gets transferred to "Opportunities" after "Qualify", I want my custom "city" field to be filled with "city" from "Account" after i create a new account record.

This has something to do with workflows right?

Please correct me if I am wrong anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311436/in-dynamic-crm-fill-in-the-field-automatically

Comment: @GuidoPreite could I have created/edited a 1:N relationship for the same? Also as I understood 1:N and N:1 is the same, we just change the entity from which we are creating/viewing it??

Comment: 1:N and N:1 are not the same, because change which entity will contain the lookup field. If for example 1 Account can have several "custom" entities, just create a lookup field inside the "custom" entity, in this way CRM will create the right relationship for you. After edit the mapping for the new relationship

Comment: o.O thanks for clearing that up mate .. one last thing .. can you please provide me with some links to "Relationship and Mapping" articles/videos/anything :) Cheers!

Comment: there isn't so much, the mapping is quite simple, you can check this link http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/06/26/microsoft-dynamics-crm-relationship-mappings-help-keep-customer-and-bill-to-customer-consistent/

Comment: Okay this is what I got from reading some articles and blog posts. When you create a 1:N relationship between A and B entity .. N:1 gets created automatically in child entity (and vice versa).. Autopopulate happens only when we create a child from parent entity  .. we use the lookup field in an entity to map the other entity instances .. Am I correct? @GuidoPreite

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the autopopulate works only when you create the record starting from the parent entity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to create a N:1 relationship on your Custom entity which points to the Account entity.  If you are not looking for a lookup field, or if the entities are otherwise already related, then the “Mappings” feature of the relationship may be worth looking into.  Keep in mind that this type of mapping only works when you are creating the “child” record from the “parent” record (with the parent form open).  If you create the record “stand-alone” it won’t auto create the mapping.  You can use workflows, however they run asynchronously and you may not see the result right away (which can confuse end users).  Aside from that your options are JavaScript (not 100% reliable) or a custom code a Plugin.