# How to map fields between Incident and follow-up phone call activity

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a custom field **new_X** on PhoneCall activity form and a custom field **new_Y** on Incident entity form. Both are of the type "whole number". When I create a **follow-up** phone call from incident form I want data from "new_Y" field to be copied to the "new_X" field on Phone Call form.

Is there any OOB way to do this? If not then what are the other ways to do this?

**Question Extended:**

I tried editing the mapping between PhoneCall activity and Incident (image below):
[image]

But under this relationship, there is no option to define the mapping (image below):
[image]

Comment: Since no mapping is defined for OOB N:1 relationship between phone call and incident entities, I created a custom N:1 relationship and mapped both the fields in that custom relationship's mapping but still the data from new_Y to new_X field is not being copied while creating a followup phone call activity. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mapping functionality, it's built-in. You can find more details here:

[In Dynamic CRM fill in the field automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311436/in-dynamic-crm-fill-in-the-field-automatically)

and here

http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2012/06/26/microsoft-dynamics-crm-relationship-mappings-help-keep-customer-and-bill-to-customer-consistent/

Comment: Hi Guido, as suggested in your post I tried to map source and target fields but I couldn't find the option to do that. I have extended my question with screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the approach in this post to get to the relationship mappings:
http://crmconsultancy.wordpress.com/tailoring-the-product-selection-for-opportunities-and-quotes-in-dynamics-crm/productcataloguemapping-mscrm-fields-from-opportunity-product-to-quote-product/

Although that post relates to Opportunity Product > Quote product, the approach might work for your scenario too. It's all about getting the relationship ID and then leveraging the URL-addressable nature of CRM windows to display the mappings screen.

Comment: I fetched the relationshipid and prepared the url as suggested in the blog but its giving me an error when i run it: "Record is unavailable". This is most likely because no mapping is defined for OOB N:1 relationship between phone call and incident entites (as shwon in screenshot in my question).